# php - Symfony: Edit information of current user login with another user and reload page show error

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.1

I have two accounts one is client account and another is admin account. Client login to his account to edit profile and submit to admin approve. the problem when admin approve his updating then click submit then in client account reload page and have problem with message too many redirection.
Below is my code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/client/personal-information", name="client_personal_info_page")
 * @Template("FrontendBundle:ClientPanel:personal_info.html.twig")
 */
public function clientPersonalInfo(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChangePersonalInfoFormType::class);
    $form->setData($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $user = $form->getData();
        $idCardPictureFront = $form->get('idCardPictureFront')->getData();
        $idCardPictureBack = $form->get('idCardPictureBack')->getData();
        $accountDocument = $form->get('accountDocument')->getData();
        if ($idCardPictureFront != null) {
            $file = new Media($idCardPictureFront);
            $this->persistAndFlush($file);
            $user->setIdCardPictureFront($file);
        }
        if ($idCardPictureBack != null) {
            $file = new Media($idCardPictureBack);
            $this->persistAndFlush($file);
            $user->setIdCardPictureBack($file);
        }
        if ($accountDocument != null) {
            $file = new Media($accountDocument);
            $this->persistAndFlush($file);
            $user->setAccountDocument($file);
        }
        if ($form->get('otherCountryCode')->getData() != null) {
            $phnoneNumber = $form->get('otherCountryCode')->getData().'-'.
                            $form->get('phoneNumber')->getData();
            $user->setPhoneNumber($phnoneNumber);
        }

        $user->setStatus(AccountStatus::PENDING_OPENING);
        $user->setPendingType(PendingType::ACCOUNT_UPDATE);
        $this->addLog(
            $this->moduleName,
            LogAction::UPDATE,
            'User update personal information',
            $user->getId()
        );

        $this->msgSuccess('frontend.client.panel.personal_info_updated');
        $this->persistAndFlush($user);

        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
    }

    return $this->getResponseParameters([
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the action in the controller where the client accesses the page?

Comment: I posted already

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, but based on your action, either your form is using the GET method to submit data and on return $this->redirect($request->getUri()); you get an error with too many redirects, or the user status of Pending is preventing him from viewing the page so the client is redirected somewhere that redirects again here. There might be an EventListener somewhere to check at request the user status and redirects the client to a page based on that status.

Comment: Ok, let me recheck again